# what started BitLocker encryption

Tags: windows, windows-11, bitlocker

I turned off BitLocker but only to find some process turned it on the next day.
Is it possible to track down what did that?

I can see events under `Microsoft-Windows-BitLocker-API/BitLocker Management` but nothing about the user/process other than `SYSTEM`.

Checked task scheduler under `\Microsoft\Windows\BitLocker`, nothing suspicious in the run history. Also checked group policy under `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Operating System Drives` I see everything not configured.

It's a corporate owned PC which connects to an AD domain already. What's interesting is that whatever process did this it doesn't happen to another PC in the same domain.

Comment: “It's a corporate owned PC which connects to an AD domain already.” - You should ask your AD Administrator the reason BitLocker is enabled only they can permanently disable it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a domain joined PC. Each time you restart your PC - and at other times too - GPOs are processed and actioned. Each GPO is a set of instructions managed centrally on your domain that configures a particular operation.

Based on your description I would expect there's either a GPO to enable BitLocker (you suggest this isn't the case, though) or maybe a start-up script that does it.

As to reasons why BitLocker doesn't get triggered on another PC? Perhaps it's misconfiguration and the PC isn't in the correct OU to have BitLocker enabled. Or maybe it's an older machine that doesn't have a TPM. You'd really have to ask your IT staff for a definitive reply to both questions.